# What's the type of HTML elements' attributes in svelte?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svelte

Usually when I'm working with svg icons in React, I move them to a separate component. The component is something like this:

```
function ShareIcon(props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) {
  return (
    <svg
      width="16"
      height="16"
      viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}
    >
      <path
        d="M12.8236 11.3369C12.2182 11.3369 11.6529 11.5378 11.2493 11.9398L5.47729 8.60324C5.51771 8.40218 5.55812 8.24124 5.55812 8.04026C5.55812 7.8392 5.51771 7.67826 5.47729 7.47728L11.1688 4.18105C11.6127 4.58305 12.1779 4.82411 12.8236 4.82411C14.1555 4.82411 15.2454 3.7386 15.2454 2.41204C15.2454 1.08555 14.1555 0 12.8236 0C11.4917 0 10.4018 1.08555 10.4018 2.41207C10.4018 2.61309 10.442 2.77407 10.4826 2.97505L4.79126 6.27128C4.34722 5.86924 3.78216 5.62822 3.13632 5.62822C1.80439 5.62822 0.754883 6.71373 0.754883 8.0403C0.754883 9.36682 1.84458 10.4524 3.17669 10.4524C3.82254 10.4524 4.3876 10.2113 4.83163 9.80928L10.5634 13.1459C10.5228 13.3065 10.4826 13.4675 10.4826 13.6684C10.4826 14.955 11.5319 16 12.8236 16C14.1153 16 15.1646 14.955 15.1646 13.6684C15.1646 12.3819 14.1153 11.3369 12.8236 11.3369Z"
        fill="currentColor"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

You can see that the type of the props is exactly the type of SVG element attributes so I can type-safely pass any SVG element's attribute as a prop to the `ShareIcon` and it will be added the actual element. Now I have a reusable icon component.

I want to do the same in Svelte.

Svelte has `$$props` that can be used to access all of the props that have been passed to `ShareIcon` (so we can spread them into the SVG element) but it's discouraged and I don't want to use it. Let's use an object instead (`svgProps`):

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let svgProps: any;
</script>
<svg {...svgProps}>
  
</svg>
```

What should the type of `svgProps`?

Answer (score 1):

The correct type should be this:

```js
export let svgProps: svelte.JSX.SVGAttributes<SVGSVGElement>;
```

(At least until the `JSX` is removed, because the new transform does not use JSX internally any more.)